# How to implement jquery like slideDown() in zepto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidedown, zepto

I am using zepto library for my mobile web site. I have recently learnt that zepto does not have `slideDown()` plugin like jquery. I would like to implement the same for zepto.

I have tried one on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/goje87/keHMp/1/). Here it does not animate while showing the element. It just flashes down. How do I bring in the animation?

PS: I cannot provide a fixed height because I would be applying this plugin to the elements whose height property would not be known.

Thanks in advace!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6zkSX/5

JavaScript:

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.slideDown = function (duration) {    
    // get old position to restore it then
    var position = this.css('position');

    // show element if it is hidden (it is needed if display is none)
    this.show();

    // place it so it displays as usually but hidden
    this.css({
      position: 'absolute',
      visibility: 'hidden'
    });

    // get naturally height
    var height = this.height();

    // set initial css for animation
    this.css({
      position: position,
      visibility: 'visible',
      overflow: 'hidden',
      height: 0
    });

    // animate to gotten height
    this.animate({
      height: height
    }, duration);
  };
})(Zepto);

$(function () {
  $('.slide-trigger').on('click', function () {
    $('.slide').slideDown(2000);
  });
});​
​
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

https://github.com/Ilycite/zepto-slide-transition

> The Zepto Slide Transition plugin add to Zepto.js the functions bellow :
>
> slideDown();
>
> slideUp();
>
> slideToggle();

Comment: This is a much better implementation

Comment: This repo has either been deleted or made private. The repo mentioned by @kennersky is still open.

Answer (score 1):

Speransky's answer was helpful, and I'm offering a simplified alternative for a common drop-down navigation list, and separated into slideUp and slideDown on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kUG3U/1/

```
$.fn.slideDown = function (duration) {
    // show element if it is hidden (it is needed if display is none)
    this.show();

    // get naturally height
    var height = this.height();

    // set initial css for animation
    this.css({
        height: 0
    });

    // animate to gotten height
    this.animate({
        height: height
    }, duration);
};
```

Comment: Just a small fix: If the element has vertical padding, after the first call the height is incorrectly calculated, resulting in a bigger object. To prevent this, use: `var height = this.height() - parseInt(this.css('padding-top')) - parseInt(this.css('padding-bottom'));`

Answer (score 1):

This would work for what you need:
https://github.com/NinjaBCN/zepto-slide-transition

Comment: This would be comment, you can comment on any post with specified reputation